# c# Float a button on top of a pictureBox

Tags: c#, window

As the title says, I have a `pictureBox` and a `button` (Windows Form Application) and I need that button to appear on top of the pictureBox as right now the pictureBox hides the button when I put them together.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Either buttton.BringToFront or button.Parent = pictureBox

Comment: are these accessible from the button properties?

Comment: BringToFront changes the z-order. Available in either designer or code. Parent: Only code. It  will __nest__ the buttton, so it will __move__ with the Picturebox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **Bring to front** operation in context menu in winforms' designer

[image: Bring to front button1.BringToFront();]

Answer (score 1):

You need the `BringToFront` method:

```
button1.BringToFront();
```

You can access this method design-time through (Right click => Bring To Front)

**When you do that, the designer is changed so that the button is added first to its parent, that way it is on top.**

Docs:

> The control is moved to the front of the z-order. If the control is a
>   child of another control, the child control is moved to the front of
>   the z-order. BringToFront does not make a control a top-level control,
>   and it does not raise the Paint event.